# Run swift script inside bash script

Tags: swift, bash, shell, command-line

I want to execute a swift script from a string inside a bash script and get a result of the execution.
I've tried a couple of variants, and can't achieve a needed result.
I do not want to use separate file to store the swift script. I want to have the swift script inside an environment variable.

```
APP="
import Foundation 

let path = CommandLine.arguments[1]
print(path)

"

#xcrun swift main.swift /path/path2/path3/path4 **this is not that I want**
#I need something like this:
xcrun swift $APP /path/path2/path3/path4
```

If I run this script I'll have an error:

> error: unable to invoke subcommand: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-import (No such file or directory)
>   How I can execute a swift script from a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `swift -` to read the source from standard input, 
and a ["here document"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)
 to provide the inline Swift code.

*Example:* Contents of `x.sh`:

```
echo "Before running Swift"
xcrun swift - /path/path2/path3/path4 <<'EOF'
import Foundation 

let path = CommandLine.arguments[1]
print(path)
EOF
echo "After running Swift"
```

Running the script:

```
$ bash x.sh
Before running Swift
/path/path2/path3/path4
After running Swift
```

Or, if you want to read the Swift code from a variable:

```
APP="
import Foundation 

let path = CommandLine.arguments[1]
print(path)

"

echo "Before running Swift"
xcrun swift - /path/path2/path3/path4 <<< "$APP"
echo "After running Swift"
```